# how to display in a mobile phone the subtitles embedded in a video in youtube?

Tags: video, mobile, youtube, subtitle

I added transcription(subtitle)on one video and it displayed correctly when we watch the video with a pc; but with a mobile phone (whatever) the subtitles no longer appears unless we activate it through the settings. How then can we make the transcript added to the video appear in mobile phone?

**NB: I'm not talking about automatic suggested translation suggested by YouTube, I'm talking about subtitle file with srt extension added to the video**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `cc_load_policy=1` in the YouTube embed code and in case there are more than one subtitle then you can also specify the language, such that : `cc_lang_pref=[language ISO code]`.
In case the below video is not running then consider opening the Iframe URL directly or running the code somewhere else.

```html
<!-- The Original Video has two subtitles: English and German. The following iframe has English subtitle turned on, you can change the subtitle language by specifying the language ISO code.-->
<iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jNQXAC9IVRw?cc_load_policy=1&cc_lang_pref=en" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer;encrypted-media;picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I wanna precise that the video is loaded directly on my youtube channel not in a html page.

Comment: I believe Users have to manually turn on subtitles on Mobile Device, you can advise the Users to turn on Captions in your Video.

Comment: I think it would be better to turn on captions automatically as in PC mode. Thank you @iamabdm for you help.